# How can I get my D3 heatmap to resize properly when using div widths instead of the viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

(**EDIT**: viewBox and preserveAspectRatio are great, but aren't rendering properly in IE9, so I can't use that.)

I've been working on resizing [this heatmap (here it is on a block)](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/133d4acec145af829845). By selecting the width of a div, appending an SVG to it, and setting my SVG's width to that of the div, I've been able to make the heatmap responsive.

Nevertheless, I've run issues when I've tried to update the heatmap on resize. Here's the resize function:

```
            d3.select(window).on("resize", resize);

            function resize(){

                marginHM = {top:35, right:0, bottom:50, left:30};
                divWidthHM = parseInt(d3.select("#chartHM").style("width"));
                widthHM = divWidthHM-marginHM.left-marginHM.right;
                gridSize = Math.floor(widthHM/24);
                legendElementWidth = gridSize*2.665;
                heightHM = (9*gridSize)-marginHM.top-marginHM.bottom;


                svgWidthHM = widthHM + marginHM.left+marginHM.right;
                svgHeightHM = heightHM+marginHM.top+marginHM.bottom;

                svgHM.select("svg").style("width", (svgWidthHM+20) + "px")
                     .style("height", (svgHeightHM+30) + "px");



                dayLabels.attr("y", function (d, i){ return i*gridSize;})
                     .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + gridSize/1.5+")");

                timeLabels.attr("x", function(d,i) {return i * gridSize;})
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + gridSize/2+", -6)");


                cards.attr("x", function(d) {return d.hour *gridSize; })
                    .attr("y", function(d) {return d.day * gridSize; })
                    .attr("width", gridSize)
                    .attr("height", gridSize);



                d3.selectAll("rect.HMLegend")
                    .attr("x", function(d, i){ return legendElementWidth * i;})
                    .attr("y", 7.2*gridSize)
                    .attr("width", legendElementWidth)
                    .attr("height", gridSize/2);

                d3.selectAll("text.HMLegendText")
                    .attr("x", function(d, i){ return legendElementWidth *i;})
                    .attr("y", 8*gridSize);

            }
```

If you [open the heatmap](http://bl.ocks.org/iblind/133d4acec145af829845) and drag the window to a wider size than it initially loaded in, you'll find that the heatmap grows, but the SVG's dimensions are cut off at the initial width; I find this really strange, considering I update the width in the resize function. You can decrease the width from its original value, and the map will size down, but you can't increase it above the original value of the width.

Additionally, I run into issues with the legend bar and legend labels. The the legend labels don't shift on window resize, and when you click back and forth between USA and New York, the legend colours often move off screen or show duplicates. Have been staring at this all evening, and am getting to the point where everything's blurring into one nonsensical line of code. Would really appreciate someone weighing in on exactly what it is I'm messing up!

Comment: Have you considered making your d3 responsive by using an SVG viewbox?

Comment: Yes, I tried that at first, but as I mentioned, I wanted to avoid this. ViewBox doesn't play nice with IE9, despite ostensibly being supported.